# Apache Camel example to insert a row in a table

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-camel

I want to insert exchange.body to a database table for one of the condition of my route.

- Is there any example/tutorial of camel-jdbc component to insert message body?
- Can I import the SQL statement itself and pass exchange.body to it?

I looked at http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html example, but could not understand it.

Here Spring example is confusing for me. I didn't get why is it setting the body as SQL query and again importing some query from the class path. (There is no insert query example mentioned here.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I looked for few examples but I am not able to understand them. I could not find any specific to inserting the message body.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I could not understand http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html example. Here Spring example is confusing for me. I didn't get why is it setting the body as sql query and again importing some query from the class path. There is no insert query example mentioned here.<br/>

Comment: jdbc component uses body as a source of SQL query. If you want to pass data in your body consider using SQL (http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) or MyBatis (http://camel.apache.org/mybatis.html) component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to do some restructure of your payload before inserting it anyway, so there should probably be no issue to do a transformation using whatever method in Camel to set the body to the appropriate INSERT statement.

The important thing is what kind of payload structure your incoming message have. In the basic case - it's a string - it should be fairly simple

```
// In a Java bean/processor before the JDBC endpoint.
// Update: make sure to sanitize the payload from SQL injections if it contains user inputs or external data not generated by trusted sources.
exchange.getIn().setBody("INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('" + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class) + "', 'fixedValue', 1.0, 42)");
```

In case your message contains complex data structures, this code will of course be more complex, but it's pretty much the same way regular application will generate SQL queries.

The classpath example you are refering to

```
 <jdbc:embedded-database id="testdb" type="DERBY">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:sql/init.sql"/>
 </jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Simply shows how to test the JDBC component by starting a Database server embedded (Apache Derby) and populate it with some initial data (the sql/init.sql file). This part is not really part of the core jdbc component, but simply in the documentation to get up and running a sample without needing to configure a DB server and setup the JDBC connection properties.

That said, you might want to use the SQL component for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Please be careful. The example makes it very easy to do a SQL injection attack. It may be possible to escape the body content though to prevent this.

Comment: Good point. I do not think there is any fool proof way to do SQL injection safe INSERT statements with the JDBC component. The data has to be sanitized manually someway. So, another reason to use the SQL component instead. OWASP and some others have written code to clean SQL Statements to some extent: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI

Comment: Another safe choice is to use the camel-jpa component. It supports adding rows to a table out of the box. Another nice thing about camel-jpa is that it also supports the other side where you read from a table and want to delete the records on success.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to insert using **the same statement** (changing the parameters only)  - use [SQL component](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html).

If you want to insert using **arbitrary SQL statement** into the component - use [JDBC component](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html).

SQL component usage:

```
from("direct:start").to("sql:insert into table foo (c1, c1) values ('#','#')");

com.google.common.collect.Lists;
producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:start", Lists.newArrayList("value1","value2"));
```

JDBC component usage:

```
from("direct:start").to("jdbc:dataSource");

producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:start", "insert into table foo (c1, c1) values ('value1','value2')");
```